# How to start ethereum classic (ETC) testnet/morden node?

Tags: testnets, ethereum-classic, morden

I want to be able to start a node that will sync to the ETC testnet (is that morden?) network and allow me to query over web3 (or other) interface.

I tried all tutorials and documentations, I tried using geth and using parity.  It never manages to connect to any node on the network and syncs nothing....

I tried using bootnodes from other (OLD) answers but without success. If I try to start the main ETC network it works.

Answer (score 0):

I connected peer using geth v5.3.0. but it have not synced latest block.
`geth --chain=morden --fast --bootnodes="enode://1fac84e8fe252d63764563f4f526323393b52aaaf832693f7a8a1637f6920311d7d04a7cb91945273e6c644d5c3b01a6bf8a172ae653c918e1bf8eb79e7e6baf@94.152.212.32:40404,enode://21101a9597b79e933e17bc94ef3506fe99a137808907aa8fefa67eea4b789792ad11fb391f38b00087f8800a2d3dff011572b62a31232133dd1591ac2d1502c8@104.198.71.200:30403,enode://30a1fd71f28aa6f66fe662af9ecc75f0a6980f06b71598f2b19d3dda04223fc0e53b47e40c9171d5014e9f5b59d9954de125782da592f5d95ea39066e2591d5d@104.237.131.102:30304,enode://3666177e0e2e56bebaef318c8ba4aed3d05ce788df1eb0e48b79fce40fcf3445feb4ccc4ce2fd4aadc3c146858e276bdef1cb63437215f17e6e5dd8c41403427@144.202.23.122:30303,enode://3666177e0e2e56bebaef318c8ba4aed3d05ce788df1eb0e48b79fce40fcf3445feb4ccc4ce2fd4aadc3c146858e276bdef1cb63437215f17e6e5dd8c41403427@45.76.16.230:30303,enode://78d8897b376e549c2b47664e4c81fd023b089d0a417275731760739b7f98dd639d632bb7b75e92606c7d6abbbe96f69f06d85e0a41a143f1f0a3c55ff2b1d732@144.202.101.214:30303,enode://7909d51011d8a153351169f21d3a7bbedb3be1e17d38c1f2fad06504dd5aa07a00f00845835d535fe702bf379c4d7209a51f4d1b723e0ca8b8732bd21fba3b30@139.162.133.42:30303,enode://a088dfb2f5305be9232e8071c5535f13718a4017e247a0b35074b807d43d99e022880c27302cdb5b1e98ad34c083dbbb483f2b17bdc66149bad037154d6ace96@139.162.127.72:30303,enode://a329e2399e6d72009690faa15a82ae13ef2015bc5e72ffb22f92ea83cf3bfc9ce45d43c38b3c2289c148939d3911e9d1a9e940f41698dba54508b59489072b2a@5.135.157.4:30303,enode://afdc6076b9bf3e7d3d01442d6841071e84c76c73a7016cb4f35c0437df219db38565766234448f1592a07ba5295a867f0ce87b359bf50311ed0b830a2361392d@104.154.136.117:30403,enode://d79b12fc48a494ba7053bbc30cbe510060ebb3a2ce9bb4f88076303e97e31e2af263c61e797af0af20419b7268b2bfb2d2f196b57242a454035ecb6001cc69a2@94.23.49.75:30303,enode://f4a1805a51cfdf5afdddf0b43b8d4b687657497311797464046dce65388b9e5a538b55bdb23ae4eac54485a81d47adad48731294efc9d73fbc9f297f625aec70@198.27.80.32:30303,enode://f570df80b5589dfb0a7657adb62b93dc55e76d491694d8965c6382964e6f397ae0b8c3548ef0a108151f3b1485c75769ff203df2db7ace385ee98fdb2766ba3b@86.8.233.254:30303,enode://fb28713820e718066a2f5df6250ae9d07cff22f672dbf26be6c75d088f821a9ad230138ba492c533a80407d054b1436ef18e951bb65e6901553516c8dffe8ff0@104.155.176.151:30304,enode://fd008499e9c4662f384b3cff23438879d31ced24e2d19504c6389bc6da6c882f9c2f8dbed972f7058d7650337f54e4ba17bb49c7d11882dd1731d26a6e62e3cb@35.187.57.94:30304"`